# Exportar archivo plano usando php , (espacios.)

Tags: php, html

Estoy exportando en `PHP` una serie de datos a un archivo `txt`. Estos tiene que tener un orden exacto, pero hay ciertos datos , que me salen con 2 espacios menos y no se que puedan ser. Estos datos son solo texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria el código con el que se realiza la exportación:

```
$memo = $row['gestion'];
$memo = str_replace("\r", ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace("\r\n", ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace("\r", ' ', $memo);

$memo = str_replace('\\\\', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace("\n", ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace("\t", ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('ñ', 'n', $memo);
$memo = str_replace(' ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace("'", '', $memo);
$memo = str_replace(",", '', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('.', '', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('  ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('   ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('    ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('     ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('      ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('       ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('  ', ' ', $memo);
$memo = str_replace('Ñ', 'N', $memo);


$memo = substr($memo, 0,500);
$memo = $this->eliminar_tildes($memo);
//$memo = $this->Espacios($memo, 500);

    if (!empty($Array[$a]['gestion'])) {
        $data .= str_pad(trim($casaCobranza),20," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['fechagestion']),21," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['contrato']),9," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['obligacion']),30," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['tipodocumento']),1," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['identificacion']),13," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($codigo), 8, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['numeromarcado']),100," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad($memo,500," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['fechapago']),10," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($Array[$a]['valorpago']),15," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['fechapromesa']),10," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['valorpromesa']),15," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($modeloCorreo), 15," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($row['motivopago']),15," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        $data .= str_pad(trim($idasesor),13," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT) . "\r\n";
    }

$a++;
```

Comment: Sube el codigo con el Exportas.

Comment: lo subi como respuesta gracias, es que apenas aprendo

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido del sitio (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)  para que entiendas mejor el funcionamiento y puedas ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: En lugar de intentar abordar uno por uno los reemplazos de múltiples espacios en blanco, intenta esto: `$memo=preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$memo);`Luego aplicas los otros reemplazos particulares y finalmente usas  `str_pad` y `trim`

Comment: Aun asi no me funciona gracias la verdad sigue el problema con **memo**

Comment: Aun asi, no se que podra ser me come espacios, nisiquiera me los agrega

Comment: ¿Y si primero le haces trim a los espacios en blanco hasta que quede 1 y luego le das una tabulación?

Answer (score 1):

El valor de `$memo` podría tener un espacio mayor al que intentas eliminar mediante:

```
$memo = str_replace('       ', ' ', $memo);
```

Te sugiero usar también la función trim() para eliminar los posibles espacios:

```
$data .= str_pad(trim($memo),500," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Realize una prueba asi, y aun me pasa lo mismo :t

Comment: @ZachIgärz ¿cual es el último valor que agregas a la linea?

Comment: recurri a ese str_replace.. por desesperacion ya no se que pueda hacer o que este haciendo mal

Comment: el ultimo valor que agrego es una identificacion, solo numeros

Comment: Con usar trim() es suficiente para evitar todos esos reemplazos. Quita los str_replace() para $memo y únicamente usa trim(), dices que el último valor es "identificacion" pero de acuerdo al código no es así, ya que estas usando $data para escribir cada linea, es así?

Comment: si yo uso $data para escribir cada linea.